# Process file with for command in alphabetical order

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, sqlcmd

I must run *n* query SQL for update more database. I created a batch file to help me in this activity but the queries are not executed ordered by name.

I use this batch command:

```
for %%I in (.\*.sql) DO sqlcmd -S .\istance -U username -P password -d dbname -i %%I -o .\%%I.log
```

How can I run all queries ordered by name?

Thanks for your answer.


*Note: I use Windows 7.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only reason for the FOR command not enumerating files in name order is that the file system is not NTFS. FAT filesystem enumerate files in drop order.

So use explicit name order enumeration

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /on *.sql') do (
    sqlcmd -S .\istance -U username -P password -d dbname -i %%i -o .\%%i.log
)
```